# Building OSDK 4.1 with OpenCV 3 and 4 installed

Tags: opencv, dji-sdk

I am trying to install OSDK 4.1 on a destkop machine using OpenCV 3.3.1 but I still have OpenCV 4.5.3-dev installed to run other things but when I call `cmake -D ADVANCED_SENSING=ON -D OpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opencv3/include/opencv2 ..` The output of build is below, and as you can see I still have a build using opencv4 to **camera_stream** and **stereo_vision**.

```
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

stereo-vision-single-thread-sample...
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

stereo-vision-multi-thread-sample...
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

camera-stream-poll-sample...
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

camera-stream-callback-sample...
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

djiosdk-liveview-sample...
-- Found OpenCV installed in the system, will use it to display image in AdvancedSensing APIs
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include/opencv4
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_alphamat;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto

stereo-vision-depth-perception-sample...
-- Found OpenCV 3.3.1 installed in the system, will use it for depth perception sample
--  - Includes: /usr/local/opencv3/include;/usr/local/opencv3/include/opencv
--  - Libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudev;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_sfm;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
-- Did not find ximgproc in OpenCV
-- Did not find viz3d in OpenCV
-- Found 11.0 CUDA installed in the system, will use it for depth perception sample
--  - Includes: /usr/local/cuda/include
-- Did not find required libraries, stereo vision depth perception sample will not be compiled.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vant3d/Onboard-SDK/build
```

I also tried to force on CMakeList define a requirement for OpenCV 3 and its pathway but just recognize on **stereo-vision-depth-perception-sample**.

Anyone already suffer on this problem and have some tips to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

in cmakelist of the your appllication, add this line

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "/path to you /opencv-4")
```

where opencv will only look in this directory instead of the system one.

Comment: I did this, but unfortunatelly when I was building it was finding the two OpenCV versions and got some conflict. My "solution" was unisnstall both and reinstall only OpenCV 4 and work with it for now.

Comment: there are multiple cmakelist in that directory you need to find them. whoever is using opencv has to have a custom link